# Working with Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: iphone, android, titanium

I am using Titanium appcelerator for developing my android application, more over i am newbie to handle both of this together, even though i have made some digging to find some  resources to start up with this, i am finding some difficulties in my first try.if anybody have resources that helps me move on further, please let me know...

Other one.. is it possible to run my android application that i have done using  Titanium appcelerator in iPhone..if so please provide some resources...for doing the same...

Please let me know....

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, titanium appcelerator apps can be packaged for the iPhone, and will work nearly the same as on android.
To do this, you need a Mac computer and the iPhone SDK (download from Apple).  I believe you also need to pay Apple US$50 to deploy your own app to the phone.
If you want to put it on the App Store, you will need to submit it for Apple's approval.
The following link may help:
http://assets.appcelerator.com.s3.amazonaws.com/docs/GettingStartedTitanium_Mac.pdf

As far as general coding goes, I found the Twitter client example helpful.